# How to Overload a method from parent to child

Tags: c++, oop

my class of animals

```
class Animal
{
protected:
    string animalName, sounds, colors, wayOfDrinking, wayOfEating;
    int numberOfLegs;
    bool hasTail;

public:
    Animal() {} //default constructor
    ~Animal() {} //destructor

    void SetAnimal(string, string, string, string, string, int, bool);
    Animal GetAnimal(void);
};

class WildAnimal : public Animal
{
    string animalPrey, attackStyle;

public:
    void SetAnimal(string, string);
};

class TameAnimal : public Animal
{
    string predator, hidingStyle;
};
```

my instance in main:

```
WildAnimal lion;
    lion.SetAnimal("Lion", "Roar!", "Gold", "Stick the tongue out", "Tear the flesh", 4, true);
    lion.SetAnimal("Stag", "Pounce");
```

I get an error in the "Gold" part saying that I'm giving too much parameters. How can I successfully overload SetAnimal method from class animal to wild animal? Thanks!

Comment: The `SetAnimal` in `WildAnimal` hides the identically named function in `Animal`. Add a `using Animal::SetAnimal;` in your `WildAnimal` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a member function in a derived class, it hides all base class member functions of the same name. To bring the base class member function into the derived class's scope so that it can be found by name lookup, add a `using`:

```
class WildAnimal : public Animal
{
    string animalPrey, attackStyle;

public:
    void SetAnimal(string, string);
    using Animal::SetAnimal;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df451626df8aa6ef).